# ExtJS4 Template parameter

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am new to extJs4 and I was trying to understand how Templates work.

My question is: How can I pass a function as parameter to the template?
Say for example I have an 'a' element and I want to handle its 'onClick' event with a custom function defined in my extjs custom class.

What I managed to do is to pass a function foo() as parameter that has a simple alert in it. 
Problem is that the alert gets triggered on the app loads, but after that when clicking the element nothing happens. Upon element inspection I saw that its onclick handler was an empty string.

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to post an example of the code you're trying to write.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Templates are just for data presentation, any logic to handle interaction with the user must be done in the containing element or its childs, here is how you use a template:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    //Some dummy data
    var data = { name: 'Jerónimo', age: 37 };

    // Declare a template to use, very simple.
    var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
        '<H1>Template sample:</H1>',
        '<tpl for=".">',
        '<p>Name: {name}</p>',
        '<p>Age: {age}</p>',
        '</tpl>'
    );

    // Apply the template to our div
    tpl.overwrite('myDiv', data);

    // Control the click event on the div
    Ext.get('myDiv').on('click', function(){ alert('Click'); });
})
```

You can check a working example here: [JsFiddle Ext 4.0.7 template example](http://jsfiddle.net/3fjCq/)

Hope that helps a bit to understand template usage.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I realize I have quite a lot to understand because from what I see ExtJS is quite large, but thanks again for your help.